# How to force maven dependency version via dependencyManagement in parent pom?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, dependency-management, transitive-dependency

Let's say `B:1.0.1` has transitive dependency `A:1.0.1`, but the child project is supposed to depend on `A:1.0.2` (with intentional overriding transitive dependencies).

It is easy to discover that the order of dependencies in `<dependencyManagement>` affect versions overriding, so adding `A:1.0.2` in the child pom just before `B:1.0.1` would force using `A:1.0.2` even as a dependency for `B:1.0.1`.

In this case I'm looking for a way to declare `A:1.0.2` in the parent pom, and remove boilerplate from all its children. Unfortunately, the following setup leads to using both versions in the final artifact: `A:1.0.1` (comes as a dependency of `B:1.0.1`) and `A:1.0.2` (comes from the explicit declaration in the parent pom).

How to force using version `A:1.0.2` in all child projects, keeping the declaration in the parent?

Parent pom:

```
<groupId>my-group</groupId>
<artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>   
    <dependency>
      <groupId>g</groupId>
      <artifactId>A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Child pom:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>my-group</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>my-child</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>   
  <dependency>
    <groupId>g</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <!-- version 1.0.2 comes from the parent pom -->
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>   
    <dependency>
      <groupId>g</groupId>
      <artifactId>B</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the dependencyManagement incorrectly.

If A and B are jar artifacts, you should not have the tags

```xml
<type>pom</type>
<scope>import</scope>
```

These are for BOMs only.

Comment: Let's assume that the type is whatever is suitable for answering this question. Then how we solve this problem with versions conflict?

Comment: Setting the version for A in the parent POM dependencyManagement will set the version for all child projects as well (unless, of course, they explicitly set their own version).